# Angular directives collaboration

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

So here I am trying to implement an autocomplete suggestion with angular and I need your expertise.

Here is the html:

```
<div my-autosuggest>
    <input type="text" my-autosuggest-input>
    <ol>
         <li ng-repeat"item in items" my-autosuggest-list>...</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

I don't want to use templates to generate `<li>` elements. (I want it to be flexible to use any kind of element in any order and maybe some other extra elements in between for the list and dropdown)

The hard part is to respond to arrow keys on the input to highlight the next/prev element in the list. How do I let the other directive `my-autosuggest-list` know that it should select the next element from `my-autosuggest-input` directive.

Note that I might have multiple autosuggests in one controller like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
   <div my-autosuggest>
       <input type="text" my-autosuggest-input>
       <ol>
            <li ng-repeat"item in items" my-autosuggest-list>...</li>
       </ol>
   </div>
   <div my-autosuggest>
       <ol>
            <li ng-repeat"item in items" my-autosuggest-list>...</li>
       </ol>
       <input type="text" my-autosuggest-input>
   </div>
</div>
```

So far I have tried to `$watch` for an index change but sometime the watch wont be called for some elements in the list (maybe it's a bug).
$broadcast won't work because the input might be wrapped in another controller or inside another element so the broadcast won't be heard by the list.

I also tried to put a variable for each autosuggest in the root scope but the order in which the directives are called in not always from parent to child so I cannot initialize that variable and create a new one each time `my-autosuggest` is called because `my-autosuggest-input` or others might be called before that.

Any suggestion on how to design this with angular is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `my-autosuggest-input` and `my-autosuggest-list` are always inside a `my-autosuggest`.  You could use a series of `$emitted` and `$broadcast` events to accomplish this.

Inside the `my-autosuggest-input`'s link function add a `$emit` when the arrow key is pressed:

```
element.on('keyup', function () {
   // Figure out if this is an arrow key, if so:
   $scope.$emit('listSelect', { message: 'prevItem' }); // Or 'nextItem'
});
```

Inside the `my-autosuggest` link function or controller add:

```
// Add a controllerId, so that the listener doesn't handle its own events.
$scope.controllerId = Math.random().toString();
$scope.$on('listSelect', function (e, data) {
    if ($scope.controllerId !== data.controllerId) {
        $scope.$broadcast('listSelect', { 
            controllerId: $scope.controllerId,
            message: data.message 
        });
    }
});
```

Finally, inside `my-autosuggest-list`'s link function or controller add:

```
$scope.$on('listSelect', function (e, data) {
    if (data.message === 'nextItem') {
        // Highlight next item.
    } else {
        // Highlight previous item.
    }
});
```

In this scenario `my-autosuggest` routes any `listSelect` events from any of its children to all of its children.

Comment: thanks, this will do the job, the only issue is that the main directive `my-autosuggest` will end up with many boilerplate code. For each event that is fired by input, dropdown, or list (like show dropdown, hidedropdown, select list item, ...) I need to add a listener to `my-autosuggest` directive and re-broadcast it. Let me know if you could think of any other solution to avoid the extra boilerplate code.

Comment: Seems like this doesn't work,   $scope.$on('listSelect', function (e, data) {
    $scope.$broadcast('listSelect', data);
});  will cause an infinite loop

Comment: I would play around with different event names / data values to reduce the boilerplate.  For instance, you could have one event named 'toList' that is addressed to the list component and the data object sent with the event could contain the actual message, 'select next item' for instance.  You make it really generic with an event 'routeAutoSuggest' and a data object like `{ target: 'list', action: 'show next item' }`.  Then `my-autosuggest` only has to have one listener.

Comment: I just updated my example to avoid the infinite loop.  Since `my-autosuggest` is re-`$broadcasting` the same event it is listening for, it needs to be able to tell if the event came from itself and ignore it.  The example accomplishes this by checking a random string on scope.  I am sure there are other ways of doing this as well.

Comment: Thanks, that would work. I believe I need to set `my-autosuggest` directive to `scope: true` to create a new scope unless the listeners could be registered on the same scope for the second html snippet I have in the question. To handle the infinite loop I played with the `$emit` event name from child to parent and parent to child. For example when arrow key is pressed I `$emit` a `selectNext_` event and listen to `selectNext_` in `my-autosuggest` and re-broadcast `selectNext` (without underscore at the end). Then in the list I just listen to `selectNext`